# Regular expression for a comma separated string

Tags: regex, string, perl

Regular expression for comma separated sub-string permutations

Hi,

I would like to define a regular expression that matches strings consisting of two sub-strings separated by a single comma.
Each sub-string may not be empty, and consists exclusively and without repetition of the characters 'A', 'G', 'C' and 'T'.
Thus, the pattern should match strings such as:

A,G
AG,CT
TC,CA     <- correct, 1st and 2nd sub-strings may have characters in common 
             ( as long as these are not repeated within the sub-string ).
GAT,CGA
CGAT,TG   <- correct, sub-strings may be of different length.
etc ...

and should not match:

,G          <- missing 1st sub-string
ACGT        <- missing comma
X,A         <- incorrect character X
AA,G        <- repetition of character A in 1st substring
AC,GGC      <- repetition of character G in 2nd sub-string
ATGA,TGG    <- repetition in both sub-strings
ATCXG,AAC   <- incorrect character X and repetition in 2nd sub-string
etc ...

So far I have:

```
/^(?=[ACGT]{1,4},[ACGT]{1,4}$)(?!.*(.).*\1.*,)(?!,.*(.).*\1).*$/ 

/^(?=[ACGT]{1,4},[ACGT]{1,4}$)(?!.*(.).*\g{1}.*,)(?!,.*(.).*\g{1}).*$/
```

also tried joining the capture groups with

```
/^(?=[ACGT]{1,4},[ACGT]{1,4}$)(?!.*(.).*\g{1}.*,.*(.).*\g{2}).*$/
```

Now, `(?=[ACGT]{1,4},[ACGT]{1,4}$)` seems to match the "two sub-strings separated by a single comma" and "consists exclusively of the characters 'A', 'G', 'C' and 'T'" through out the string; `(?!.*(.).*\1.*,)` seems to match "without repetition" up to the comma.

However, `(?!,.*(.).*\1)` appears not to be ensuring that it doesn't match a repeated character after the comma.

I'd greatly appreciate replies with clues and/or patterns that help with the desired matching.

Using perl v5.18.2

Thanks in advance

Robert

Comment: This gave me something fun to try with using named capture groups. Thanks, Robert! I hope one of our answers works well for your set-up :) StackOverflow is a great place to get Regex help and advice! Could I ask what kind of functionality this is needed for? I'm wondering what context this pattern recognition could be used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break your problem into steps.

First look for allowed format and characters.  Then check to make sure there is no repetition.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /^[ACGT]+,[ACGT]+$/ && !/(\w)\w*\1/;
}

__DATA__
A,G
AG,CT
TC,CA
GAT,CGA
CGAT,TG
,G
ACGT
X,A
AA,G
AC,GGC
ATGA,TGG
ATCXG,AAC
```

Outputs:

```
A,G
AG,CT
TC,CA
GAT,CGA
CGAT,TG
```

Comment: Very neat. But I sympathise with the regex engine!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pretty close. This should work as well.
It basically does what @Miller's does.

*updated* - a condensed version.

```
 #  /(?m)^(?:(?:^|,)(?:([AGCT])(?![AGCT]*\1)){1,4}){2}$/

 (?m)                   # Multiline mode
 ^                      # BOL
 (?:                    # Total cluster
      (?: ^ | , )            # BOL or comma
      (?:                    # AGCT Cluster grp
           ( [AGCT] )             # (1), Capture single character [AGCT]
           (?!                    # Negative lookahead
                [AGCT]*                # As many [AGCT] needed
                \1                     # to find what is captured in group 1
           )                      # End Negative lookahead
      ){1,4}                 # End  AGCT Cluster grp 1-4 characters
 ){2}                   # Total cluster, do 2 times  
 $                      # EOL
```